# Bulk Load in HBase Using Spark

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hbase, rdd

I am using `HBase Version 1.2.0-cdh5.8.2` and `Spark version 1.6.0`.

I am using `toHBaseTable()` method of `it.nerdammer.spark.hbase` package to save `RDD` of `Spark` in `HBASE`.

```
val experiencesDataset = sc.parallelize(Seq((001, null.asInstanceOf[String]), (001,"2016-10-25")))
experiencesDataset .toHBaseTable(experienceTableName).save()
```

But I want to save data in `HBase` using `Spark` by `Bulk Load`.

I am not able to understand how to use Bulk Load option. Please assist me.

Comment: Someone please help on this..

Comment: I didi this , hope it will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34589798/how-to-implement-the-hbase-secure-bulk-load/34613641#34613641